# How would another user reach your home directory using a relative path from his own home directory?

Tags: command-line, paths

How would another user reach your home directory starting
from his own home directory, using a relative path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your home directory and the other user's home directory follow the standard i.e. they both reside under `/home` (or reside under common parent), the other user from his/her home (`/home/<other_user>`) can do (given they have sufficient permission):

```
cd ../<your_username>
```

`..` denotes the parent directory of the present working directory.

For example, if your username is `foobar`, then the other user can do:

```
cd ../foobar
```

to change the working directory from his home to your home.

One can use the relative path  `../foobar` with other commands in a similar fashion e.g.:

```
ls -l ../foobar
```

to list the content of your home directory from other user's home.

Here is one unusual case, let's say your home directory is `/usr/foobar` and other user's home directory is `/usr/foo/spamegg`, then from his/her home (`/usr/foo/spamegg`), the other user can do:

```
cd ../../fooobar
```

On the other hand, if the parent directories of your home and the other user's home do not reside under same directory below root directory (`/`), you should not use relative path to reach one from another, you should use absolute path.

What i meant is, there is no point of doing:

```
cd ../../../usr/foobar/
```

when you can do:

```
cd /usr/foobar/
```

Comment: You can *always* use a relative path to reach somewhere you can get to with an absolute path since if you keep going up you will eventually reach the root, and then you can go back down again.

Comment: @psusi I know but i do not see the point of `../../../usr/foobar` rather than `/usr/foobar`..

Comment: Because the ink on my `.` key is too shiny, and I'd like to wear it down?

Comment: @CharlesGreen sorry, my sarcasm detector is not working i.e. i don't understand..

Comment: @heemayl I may be getting tired and cranky - I also do not see the point of `../../../usr/foobar` as opposed to the shorter and easier to comprehend absolute path.

Comment: I agree that an absolute path may be shorter and when it is, it makes sense to take the shorter of the two; I'm just pointing out that it is still possible, even if it is longer but you said it isn't.

Comment: @psusi Well, sorry for my poor choice of words..i have modified my answer..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that they are in the same partition, and that all user directories are in the same `/home` root:

`ls ../<Poopballoon12>` executed from my home directory, will list your home directory.

Comment: Really? Poopballoon?

Comment: @HeatherBrown Not me!!!!!  Look at the username of the person posting the question!!!!!!